# How can I turn a reStructured Text API directive into a heading?

Tags: python-sphinx

I provide fairly lengthy documentation for my APIs (mostly examples), and have discovered that it's better to have one page per (complete) part of the API. Currently, my reStructured Text looks like this:

```
``std::vector``
===============

.. cpp:class:: template<class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>> std::vector;

  ...
```

The heading is redundant since the `cpp:class` directive immediately follows it, but is it necessary for Sphinx to generate the page in toctrees?

I'd ideally like to promote the `cpp:class` directive to a heading, and have toctrees extract the entity name from the directive (in this case the toctree would display `std::vector`). As a rough approximation, this might look like one of the two snippets below.

```
.. cpp:class:: template<class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>> std::vector;
==================================================================================

  ...
```

```
.. cpp:class:: template<class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>> std::vector;
  :heading: 1

  ...
```

Is this something that's already possible, or would I need to extend Sphinx to achieve such functionality?